# Hibernate Projections Set<Object> @ManyToMany

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have 2 entity classes as Account and Mail , they are connected to each other by @ManyToMany.
Account entity has many Mail entities and Mail entity has many Account entities.I need to take Mail's bcc, cc, from.

My criteria is below;

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Mail.class, "t");
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                  .add(Projections.property("mailId"), "mailId")
                  .add(Projections.property("title"), "title")
                ).setResultTransformer(Transformers .aliasToBean(Mail.class));
        List<Mail> Mails = (List<Mail>)criteria.list();
```

But when I add  ***.add(Projections.property("from"), "from")*** this code, trying to get Set "from","cc" or "bcc",  I get errors, I have searched too much but I could not find a way to get successfully.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIL")
public class MAIL implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1196398352385977136L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MAIL_ID")
    private Integer mailId;


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "MAIL_FROM_ACCOUNT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MAIL_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") })
private Set<Account> from = new HashSet<Account>(0);

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "MAIL_TO_ACCOUNT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MAIL_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") })
private Set<Account> to = new HashSet<Account>(0);


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "MAIL_BCC_ACCOUNT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MAIL_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") })
private Set<Account> bcc = new HashSet<Account>(0);
```

And my other class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6230400682491920993L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private int accountId;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "from", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Mail> fromMails = new HashSet<Mail>(0);

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "to", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Mail> toMails = new HashSet<Mail>(0);

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "to", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Mail> bccMails = new HashSet<Mail>(0);

//getter and setters
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1774)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)

Comment: I noticed in your `Account` class the setter for bccMails is set to `mappedBy = "to"`. Shouldn't this be `mappedBy = "bcc"` instead?

Comment: sorry friend it's copy error.That's "bcc" actually.